# Not able to access kafka broker created in docker from hosting machine

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am running with same problem, and followed @Robin Moffatt blog. However i couldn't fix the issue. furnished details below, can someone sheds light on this?!

[image]

Here is my docker-compose.yml

[image]

> **Error (NOTE: I tried with  --zookeeper localhost:2181 as well)**
>
> [image]

Comment: Please use text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CLI command shows port 32181 for Zookeeper

Your compose file only forwards 2181 to 2181. There is no port 32181

Note: latest Kafka releases are able to do `kafka-topics --bootstrap-servers` and you should rarely need to use zookeeper.